# Is there any performance hit when we reference multiple columns to one table rather than separate tables?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a database design like this. I am using MYSQL.
Have a vehicle table to store information about a vehicle

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`vehicle` (
`vehicle_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`fuel_type_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`drive_type_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`condition_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`transmission_type_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`vehicle_id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

I used separate tables to store records for each reference id.
for eg: I have a fuel type table to store fuels, transmission type table and so on.

But now I figured that the schema of those tables are pretty much equivalent. 
So created a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`vehicle_feature` (
  `veh_feature_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feature_type_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`veh_feature_id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

and I put all those fuels and transmisiion types into this table with a feature type Id to identify the group.
Now I have to join same table again and again to retrieve the values from my vehicle table.

So my question is.

Shall I maintain my separate tables or Shall I go with this new approach? Since I have to write same joins again and again there is no reduce in my code. I can easily join my small tables rather than this one table. Also if I use small tables I can go for inner join to join those tables but in here I have to use left joins to join the tables.Also separate tables have less records comparing to one table. All what this approach doing is reduce the tables of my DB( only  4 tables which I dont care ). Sum of all records in these 4 tables will be 100 records.

So what is performance wise good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a difficult question, because these are both reasonable approaches.  The key to deciding is understand what the application needs from this type of data.

A separate table for the items has one nice advantage because foreign key constraints can actually check the referential integrity of the data.  Furthermore, each of the entities is treated as a full-fledged bona-fide entity.  This is handy if you have other information about the fuels, drives, and transmissions that is specific to that entity.  For instance, the fuel could have an octane rating, which could be in the fuel table but does not need to clutter the other reference tables.

On the other hand, you might end up with lots of similar reference tables.  And, for your application, these may not need to be full-fledged entities.  In that case, having a single table is quite reasonable.  This is actually a bigger advantage if you want to internationalize your application.  That is, if you want to provide the names of things in multiple languages.

In an object-oriented language, you would approach this problem using inheritance.  The three "types" would all be "subclasses" from a class of vehicle attributes.  Unfortunately, SQL does not have such built-in concepts.

From a performance perspective, the two methods would both involve relatively small reference tables (I'm guessing at most a few thousand rows), that are accessed via primary keys.  There should be very little performance difference between the two approaches.  The important concern is how to properly model the data for your application.

Comment: Thank you gordon. Actually sum of all records in these 4 tables will be 100 records.  So one table will suffice right?

Comment: @Sylar . . . If you only have the name column and no others, and you don't need the referential integrity checks for the ids (that validates that the fuel type id is not pointing to a transmission type record), then one table is fine.